# How to lookup value with multiple criteria in excel 2007 and newer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to lookup for a value in excel table with multiple criteria. I have tried this:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$10=A13)*($C$2:$C$10=A13),0))
```

but it doesn't work.

I use this one:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(Reservation!$A:$A=$A20)/(Reservation!$B:$B=F$5)/(Reservation!$D:$D=0),Reservation!$C:$C)
```

... which works fine, but it's extremely slow.

Is there anyway to use index with multiple criteria?

Comment: Works for me.  Just enter that with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` since it is an array formula

Comment: Why are you using entire column references in the LOOKUP version? You aren't in the INDEX version, so why here? That's forcing it to calculate over more than a million rows' worth of data. Unlike e.g. COUNTIF(S)/SUMIF(S), array formulas (which is technically what LOOKUP is in this use, despite the fact that it does not require entering with CSE) calculate over all cells passed to them, whether technically beyond the last-used cells in those ranges or not.

Comment: Note that if there are multiple rows where the conditions are true then your INDEX/MATCH version will find the first match, but the LOOKUP option will return the last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally with a single criteria all you would have to do is type:

```
INDEX($D$2:$D$10,MATCH(A13,$B$2:$B$10,0))
```

And hit <kbd>enter</kbd> and you are done.

However, since you are using arrays inside your `MATCH` formula i.e. `($B$2:$B$10=A13)` and `($C$2:$C$10=A13)` you need to enter your formula using:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

If you want further reading you can see Microsoft's [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7)

Comment: Thanks a lot Chancea, it works when I hit with ctrl + shift + enter!
This is the trick.