# Median for frequency distribution

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in excel that looks similar to the following:

```
|          |  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
|----------|---|---|---|---|---|
|Question 1| 18| 20|  1|  1|  0|
|Question 2|  9| 18|  9|  4|  4|
|Question 3| 11| 10| 13|  6|  0|
|Question 4|  4| 18| 10|  8|  0|
```

The table shows how many people chose any of the 5 possible answers (1-5) for several questions.

I have tried the solutions that barry houdini suggested here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/530046-find-medians-frequency-distribution-table.html

But I get #N/A error.

This is the exact formula that I used for data in B9:F18 and values in B8:F8:

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(INT(SUM(B9:F9)/2+{0.5,1}),SUBTOTAL(39,OFFSET(A9,,,1,COLUMN(B9:F9)-COLUMN(B9)+1))+1,B$8:F$8))/2
```

Comment: Is SUBTOTAL(39... correct?

Comment: I think so... as there are 40 values for each question to calculate the median of.

Comment: Are you using `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`?  See [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29703925/how-to-lookup-value-with-multiple-criteria-in-excel-2007-and-newer/29704380#29704380) that covers this

Comment: 39 is not a valid value for the first argument of `SUBTOTAL`.

Comment: @chancea - I have used ctrl + shift + enter

Comment: @ Mr. Mascaro I changed it to 9 like in the given example and it seems to work!  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need CTRL+shift+enter for this formula

Comment: @barryhoudini Ah my bad I just glanced and saw the `{0.5,1}` so I initially assumed you did.

Comment: @Jeeped, questions that are the result of a simple typo are off topic on this site.  The OP should have typed 9 instead of 39.

Comment: @Mr.Mascaro - Fair enough. Reminding users to check typing and syntax is not entirely a bad thing but probably beyond the scope of this site's Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in the comments, there was an error in your subtotal function as 39 is not valid for the first argument.

Subtotal takes the form
`SUBTOTAL(function_num, ref1, ref2, ...)`

where
"Function_num is the number 1 to 11 (includes hidden values) or 101 to 111 (ignores hidden values) that specifies which function to use in calculating subtotals within a list."

`| Function_num (includes hidden values) | Function |
|---------------------------------------|----------|
| 1                                     | Average  |
| 2                                     | COUNT    |
| 3                                     | COUNTA   |
| 4                                     | MAX      |
| 5                                     | MIN      |
| 6                                     | PRODUCT  |
| 7                                     | STDEV    |
| 8                                     | STDEVP   |
| 9                                     | SUM      |
| 10                                    | VAR      |
| 11                                    | VARP     |`

Or 101-111 for ignoring hidden values.

See [Excel SUBTOTAL function reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-e27c301c-be9a-458b-9d12-b9a2ce3c62af?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

The formula works nicely with `9` in place of `39`, which solves the stated problem.

For the record I believe it can be shortened a little and made non-volatile which may be preferable:

```
=SUM(LOOKUP(INT(SUM(B9:F9)-{1,0})/2,SUMIF(B$8:F$8,"<"&B$8:F$8,B9:F9),B$8:F$8))/2
```

Another way to calculate the median for a frequency distribution is by linear interpolation of the cumulative frequencies. For this method you can try:

```
=PERCENTILE(B8:F8,PERCENTRANK(INDEX(SUMIF(B$8:F$8,"<="&B$8:F$8,B9:F9),),SUM(B9:F9)/2,30))
```

(Note that for this method the median is not well defined if it falls inside the first category (<1) unless you include a lower bound such as 0.)

Comment: Hi, can you explain the working of the first method/ formula